# How to read JSON file from live server?

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a JSON file that is working properly locally but when I load it from server then it give me error that file is not found.

Here's my [gist](https://gist.github.com/taleeb35/73511c375562078e71c7):

```
var app=angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ui.router']);

app.controller('linksCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
  $http.get("papers.com.pk/API/api/json_files/03-08-2015.json")
     .success(function (response) {
         $scope.ads = response;
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please narrow down where your problem might be coming from? Does the JSON file exist on the server?

Comment: http://papers.com.pk/API/api/json_files/03-08-2015.json

Comment: $http.get("papers.com.pk/API/api/json_files/03-08-2015.json")
     .success(function (response) { });

Comment: I also tried jsonp but it is not working

Comment: `curl http://papers.com.pk/API/api/json_files/03-08-2015.json` worked perfectly for me. The file is found. Can you show the rest of your code please, in the question?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/taleeb35/73511c375562078e71c7    Here is my gist

Comment: Can you highlight where i am wrong @JoshBeam?

Comment: The code looks fine. That tells me there's an error somewhere else. Try chaining `.then(onSuccess, onFailure)` with both callbacks and see what the response is.

Comment: From other domain you cannot read data because they denied us for access the data

Comment: @JoshBeam I have 1 more question.In the link where is 03-08-2015 I want to use date variable that show me the current date in controller.Mean that d-m-Y in the link

Comment: can you share the full error....?

Comment: http://papers.com.pk/API/api/json_files/03-08-2015.json.....     In the link date is hard coded i want to make it dynamic and want to show current date